# C fwrite() stuck cpu at 100%

Tags: c, debian-based

I have a master PC and multiple slave network device. The master create a process for every slave with fork. Each process try to connect to the proper device and capture the data via TCP.

Everything worked fine, but I had a reinstall on master ubuntu->kali (4.19.0-kali1-amd64) and data capture stopped

The input data should be between  10-40Mb/s

The forking, slaves, and data capture seems to be good. As I seen the problem is the fwrite.

If I change the fwrite to printf and redirect the data into a file then I got the captured data.

Interesting notes after debugging:

- One thread of CPU was always 100%
- Always captured 16K data

Using printf instead of fwrite, everything was fine.

And another interesting note: I think it's a different problem, but my network interface can't see the incoming packages. It's captured but cannot use for statistic like netstat.

```
while(1)
      {
        valread = read( sock , buffer, 1024); //blocking
        //printf("%s",buffer); //try with printf
        if (valread > 0)
        fwrite(buffer,1,valread,fp); //stuck?
      }
```

Comment: What if you change `fp` to `stdout`?

Comment: Same for every 'printf, fprintf, fwrite. fp or stdout' doesn't matter.

Comment: Do you really need a C program for this? It sounds like you're doing work `nc` or `socat` (if you need heavy artillery) can do in a more battle-tested way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your loop doesn't stop when you get EOF or error, it just keeps trying to read from the socket.

```
while(1)
{
    valread = read( sock , buffer, 1024);
    if (valread > 0) {
        fwrite(buffer,1,valread,fp);
    } else if (valread < 0) {
        perror("read from sock");
        break;
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

EOF will occur when the device closes the network connection.

If the socket is non-blocking, `read()` can return `-1` with `ERRNO == EWOULDBLOCK` when there's nothing ready to read. You need to check for this and break out of the loop (use `select()` or `epoll()` to wait for the socket to become ready before trying to read from it).

BTW, you shouldn't use `printf()`, since `read()` doesn't add a null terminator to the buffer.

Comment: Yes, it could do some nasty thing, but I don't have any socket error during read.

Comment: "I don't have any socket error during read" How do you know that?

Comment: I have to take it back. The CPU overhead is because of the infinite loop of nonblocking read. I have tested separately and the write itself does not wrong. So probably the problem with the socket.

Comment: @RandomCounter The comment in the code says "blocking". Why are you using non-blocking reads?

Comment: By mistake. I will check it.

Comment: There were some misunderstanding for me. To make things clear:

-socket is blocking by default.  SOCK_NONBLOCK flag was not set.

-read() function is for blocking read. If the socket is nonblocking, then it will return as -1 and set errno.

The return code is 0 after 16Kb data.  So the "error" is EOF. Probably there is some problem with my connecton or with my setup.